# unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn" In Docker (and additional questions)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fastapi, uvicorn

So I am trying to dockerise an api built with fastapi and with several dependencies, i came out with this dockerfile :

```
# Making a parent image (lightweight Debian with Python installed)
FROM python:3.11-alpine

# Install build dependencies
RUN apk update --update-cache && \
    apk add --no-cache gcc build-base libpq rust cargo && \
    apk add --no-cache libffi-dev openssl-dev


# Create a directory into this operating system
WORKDIR /iseProject
COPY . .

RUN echo $(python3 -m site --user-base)
# Configuration
RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev
RUN python3 -m venv .venv



# Use the activate script directly without 'source'
RUN . .venv/bin/activate && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python -m pip install multidict && \    
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    

# Setting ENV variables for the .env 
# ARG ENV_FILE
# COPY $ENV_FILE .env 

# Enabling the exposed port 
EXPOSE 4001

ENV NAME World


# Starting the app inside the IMAGE
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4001", "--reload"]
```

but when I try to run the container, I get this error :

> User hold this in you :  failed to create task for container: failed
> to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed:
> unable to start container process: exec: "uvicorn": executable file
> not found in $PATH: unknown

what should I do ?

Also, the .env do not seem to be in the container (I replaced the CMD command with ls to check) , how can I get the .env into the image/container ?

And also, each time i rebuild the image, the installation takes always the same time, I searched about how can cache it but i dont seem to get it right (it always breaks) , so how can i do it ?

I tried :

- looking for the path with inspecting the image, and unvicorn isnt in it  but i cannot get to run a command because the container do not even start !
- i tried changing the distro, didnt work

Comment: I don't think you can `RUN . .venv/bin/activate` like that, it's not going to keep that state / venv in the next steps, you'd have to activate the venv in the command or run something like `./venv/bin/uvicorn` without activating. And those .env files require docker-compose afaik https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/env-file/ (assuming you want to have their content automatically set inside the container)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as @zapl suggests in a comment, is that while you have activated your virtual environment in your `RUN` task, that's not a persistent change -- activing a virtual environment works by setting some environment variables, and a process can only change environment variables for itself and any child processes.

Those changes are gone as soon as the `RUN` task completes.

There are a couple of ways of solving this.

1. You can provide a full path to the `uvicorn` executable:

   ```
     CMD ["./.venv/bin/uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4001", "--reload"]
   ```
2. You can explicitly activate the environment as part of your `CMD`:

   ```
   CMD . .venv/bin/activate; uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4001 --reload
   ```

   Note that here we're using the shell form of the `CMD` directive, rather than the "exec" form (because we're explicitly using shell features).
3. Lastly, you can just ditch the virtual environment. We use virtual environments to isolate the dependencies of a Python application, but that is *also* why we use containers. You can simply `pip install` things directly to the default locations in your image.

   Here's a simplified version of your Dockerfile that does that:

   ```
   # Making a parent image (lightweight Debian with Python installed)
   FROM python:3.11-alpine

   # Create a directory into this operating system
   WORKDIR /iseProject

   COPY requirements.txt ./

   RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
       pip install -r requirements.txt

   ENV NAME World

   COPY . ./

   # Starting the app inside the IMAGE
   CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4001", "--reload"]
   ```

Note in the above Dockerfile how I'm using *two* `COPY` commands -- one just for `requirements.txt` and one for everything else. Structuring your Dockerfile this way is a good idea regardless of which of the above solutions you choose, because it dramatically increases the cacheability of the build process -- you won't need to re-install all your dependencies just because you've added a comment to the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hello larsks ! thank you for your help, in fact i tried the 3 ways, only the second one (explicitly activating the env) worked
i will try with the env right now !

Comment: All three mechanisms presented here work successfully using a simple fastapi application, and I would honestly recommend option 3 in most cases. In your shoes I would try to understand why option 3 is failing, because that seems very odd. You can see my complete test [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-77916620-fastapi-container).